# Check which strings from list never appear in recursive search of directoy

Tags: shell, grep, pipe

I have a list of strings `stringList`, where I want to recursively search a directory and find all of the strings in `stringList` that did *not* appear in any search result. Right now, I have

`cat stringList | grep -qrf /dev/stdin .`

but then I do not sure where to go after that.

E.g. I have strings

foo

bar

baz

Only foo exists in a file in the directory. The script should return

bar

baz

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Add sample input / expected output

Comment: @GillesQuenot I added additional details, can you let me know if I need to add more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
string="foo
bar
baz"
echo "$string" | grep -v "$(find . -type f -exec cat {} + | grep -o "$string")"
```

This approach was chosen because it reads through the input files only once.

#### How it works

- `find . -type f -exec cat {} +`

  This does a recursive search for files and prints their contents to stdout.
- `grep -o "$string"`

  This selects any text matching the lines of `$string`.
- `echo "$string" | grep -v "$(find . -type f -exec cat {} + | grep -o "$string")"`

  `grep -v` returns any line in string that is not found in one of the files from the recursive search.

#### Example

Consider a directory with files under it containing:

```
$ find . -type f -exec cat {} +
bar none
Here baz scaggs
behind bars
bazooka
```

If we add grep, we get just the matching words:

```
$ find . -type f -exec cat {} + | grep -o "$string"
bar
baz
bar
baz
```

Putting it all together, we determine that `foo` is the only word not in the files:

```
$ echo "$string" | grep -v "$(find . -type f -exec cat {} + | grep -o "$string")"
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `gawk` as:

```
find . -type f -print0 | gawk -v listfile=/path/to/stringList '
  BEGIN{
    while ((getline string < listfile) > 0) list[string]
    RS="\0"
    while ((getline file < "/dev/stdin") > 0) ARGV[ARGC++] = file
    RS="\n"
  }
  {for (s in list) if (index($0, s)) delete list[s]}
  END {for (s in list) print s}'
```